# The scheduler instance<>is still active but was recovered by another instance in cluster. This may cause inconsistent behaviour

Tags: jet

When I start jet server, it throws following error

> the scheduler instance<>is still active but was recovered by another instance in cluster. This may cause inconsistent behaviour

How to solve this problem? I search in Google, there are many solution given but didn't solve my problem.